# HttpContext.Current sometimes null

Tags: asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc

In a web application, I need to store variables in a HttpContext.Current.Session.

I do this in conjunction with requests being made (controller -> mid tier/communication layer -> business layer -> Access layer -> Db) and also when the response is sent back to the client.

The session variables are stored in the mid tier/communication layer.

However, sometimes HttpContext.Current is null, and therefore the session is not available for storing or getting variables therein. I read in posts elsewhere that this is because it is being called from the wrong thread. And that if it was called from the web/client-side project than this would never happen.

Do you know of any solution to this, i.e. to ensure getting the current session is always available? Or any alternative way to store away session variables?

Comment: Are you using `Task.ContinueWith` or `.ConfigureAwait(false)`?

Comment: To be honest, I cannot tell for sure (need to get back for that). Although I know that ConfigureAwait(false) could result in being put on a different thread when the response is being sent back to the client.